# What is Office Authorization plug-in for NPAPI browsers for

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-office

After installing Microsoft Office, there is an *Office Authorization plug-in for NPAPI browsers* in about:plugins page in Chrome. Is this supposed to open Office documents directly in the browser? But every time I click an .doc or .ppt file, Chrome still prompts an download dialog instead of using this plugin. How to config it then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn’t a plugin to view Office documents in a browser, at least not directly. Rather, it is a plugin to provide support for [*Office Web Apps*](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/) which is basically Microsoft’s version of Google Docs. If you use Office Web Apps, then you will need to keep the plugin enabled, otherwise you can disable it.